# Can this broken proof (of multiplicative of $\varphi$) attempt be fixed?

Tags: number-theory

I wanted to prove that $\varphi$ is multiplicative (that for $(a,b)=1$, $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$) using the following idea:

- Define $\varphi'$ by $n = \varphi'(n) + \varphi(n)$.
- Multiply out $\varphi(a)\varphi(b) = (a - \varphi'(a))(b - \varphi'(b)) = ab - \varphi'(a)b - a \varphi'(b) + \varphi'(a)\varphi'(b)$
- Use the principle of inclusion exclusion ($|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|$).

but I could not get it to work out.

Is this approach possible at all? How can it be saved?

---

So I just need to construct sets $A(a,b)$ and $B(a,b)$ that satisfy the following

$$\begin{matrix}
\varphi'(ab) &=& \varphi'(a) b &+& a \varphi'(b) &-& \varphi'(a)\varphi'(b)\\
|| & & || & & || & & || \\
|A \cup B| &=& |A| &+& |B| &-& |A \cap B|
\end{matrix}$$

then the proof follows from simple algebra. I just cannot find any way to construct such sets - since the identity is true I imagine they do exist but I am not be completely sure especially since I couldn't construct them.

Comment: Chandru1: Euler's totient function, the size of the set of numbers coprime and below the argument. It can also be considered the size of multiplicative group $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times$ (which gives a very direct proof).

Comment: Where is $\varphi$ defined ($\mathbb{Z}$?) and where is it's value ($\mathbb{C}$)?

Comment: AD. $\varphi : \mathbb N \rightarrow \mathbb N$

Comment: I don't understand why this would be useful.  For one thing, you aren't using any properties of the totient.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan, It is very possible that my attempt is just mislead - I'm not sure how I could ascertain that myself though. Also I updated the question to pinpoint one thing, which if resolved, would let the result follow.

Comment: Also does anyone know how to do a vertical equals symbol? (I used || since I couldn't find how to do a proper one)

Comment: @muad: In regular LaTeX you can use a `\rotatebox` command, but I do not know if the interpret supports it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, I see.  In $\mathbb{Z}/(ab)\mathbb{Z}$ let $A$ be the set of elements not relatively prime to $a$ and let $B$ be the set of elements not relatively prime to $b$.  From here what you want follows by the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  (Of course, you could just use CRT from the get-go.)